# noun or adjective

Tags: adjectives, nouns

> You sleep longer than normal.

In this sentence, is 'normal' used as a noun or an adjective? If it is used as a noun, then is this sentence correct after "than" as I think "than" is used
to compare two same word class. In this sentece,does it compare "longer" with "normal"?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, the word normal is being used as a noun in this sentence.

  [Normal(NOUN)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/normal)

  > [mass noun] The usual, typical, or expected state or condition:
  >
  > ‘her temperature was above normal’
  >
  > ‘the service will be back to normal next week’
- Though it may not look like it, the comparison in the sentence is between your sleep and others' sleep. In your sentence, normal refers to "the usual, typical, or expected" duration of sleep. You sleep longer than normal is, in fact, a comparison between your duration of sleep and the normal duration of sleep. Try looking at the sentence this way:

  > You sleep longer than people usually do.

  It's the same as saying

  > Your sleep is longer than other people's (sleep).